# How to automatically name and concatenate cells from different operations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, concatenation, cell

I wrote a sample code to illustrate my problem - see below. I have several operations, where each is executed independently (not only 4 as in the example, but more). I want to...

1) Automate the naming of the results so that I can do it for a larger number of years, parts of years and plant types (e.g. name the variable "string200811" when Year = 2008, PartOfYear = 1, PlantType = 1 etc.)

2) Automate the concatenation, too (see below).

Let me know if anything is unclear!

```
% Operation 1
Year = 2008;
PartOfYear = 1;
PlantType = 1;
string200811 = 'blabla'; % some random result
number200811 = rand(1); % some other random result
vector200811 = [rand(1); rand(1); rand(1); rand(1)]; % some other random result

% Operation 2
Year = 2008;
PartOfYear = 1;
PlantType = 2;
string200812 = 'blablablubb';
number200812 = rand(1);
vector200812 = [rand(1); rand(1); rand(1); rand(1)];

% Operation 3
Year = 2008;
PartOfYear = 2;
PlantType = 1;
string200821 = 'blablabla';
number200821 = rand(1);
vector200821 = [rand(1); rand(1); rand(1); rand(1)];

% Operation 4
Year = 2008;
PartOfYear = 2;
PlantType = 2;
string200822 = 'blablablablubb';
number200822 = rand(1);
vector200822 = [rand(1); rand(1); rand(1); rand(1)];

% Concatenate results
Results = {2008, 1, 1, string200811, number200811;...
           2008, 1, 2, string200812, number200812;...
           2008, 2, 1, string200821, number200821;...
           2008, 2, 2, string200822, number200822}
Table = cell2table(Results);
writetable(Table,'ResultsTest.xls','Sheet',1);

vectors = vertcat(vector200811, vector200812, vector200821, vector200822)
```

Comment: Please give an example of what `C` is and what you expect your output to be. "Do the opposite" isn't a very clear description of what you want to happen...

Comment: Probably you need `C{end}`. But we need a [MCVE] to understand what exactly your problem is

Comment: I believe this question being deleted was a mistake. I understand it was off-topic in its original wording, but I completely changed it and the question is very clear now and the answer verifiable thanks to the code I posted. That´s why I´ll repost the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve what you want using [`cellfun(func, C)`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), which:

> calls the function specified by function handle `func` and passes elements from cell array `C`

So a simple example would be

```
 % Cell array of vectors
 C = {[1 2 3], [4 5 6], [7 8 9], [10 11 12]};
 % Get the "end" (last) element of each of the cell array's members
 output = cellfun(@(x) x(end), C);
 >> output = [3 6 9 12]
```

To make this a column vector instead of a row vector, simply transpose it

```
 output = cellfun(@(x) x(end), C).'; % Column vector output
```

This is "concatenating the last elements of each set of cells".

Comment: Thank you! That is useful, but as several people suggested that my question is too broad, I now posted a complete code that hopefully clarifies my specific problem.